# How a client app connect to an SSL server with a self-signed certificate in Qt?

Tags: qt, ssl, certificate, self-signed

I want to communicate with a POP3 server with ssl and port 995 with my client app
the certificate of server is self-signed and while running the app the error that received is:

> The certificate is self-signed, and untrusted

A part of code is:

```
socket = new QSslSocket(this);
QFile certfile("D:\\hani\\cert\\localhost.localdomain.pem");
Q_ASSERT(certfile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly));
QList<QSslCertificate> certList;
QSslCertificate cert(&certfile,QSsl::Pem);
certList.append(cert);
socket->addCaCertificate(cert);
socket->setCaCertificates(certList);
QList<QSslCertificate> serverCert = socket->caCertificates();
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 8):

DO NOT, let me repeat, DO NOT call `ignoreSslErrors()`. It completely defeats the purpose of SSL/TLS. There are *very* special cases where it can be called safely, but this (self-signed certificate) is not a special case.

The following minimal code, ready to run, shows how to *securely* accept a server self-signed certificate. Do not shortcut it.

The driver:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
    QTextStream log(stdout);
    DummyClient dummy(log);
    QObject::connect(&dummy, SIGNAL(done()), &app, SLOT(quit()));
    return app.exec();
}
```

The `DummyClient` class:

```
/*
 * Show how to safely authenticate a TLS server which uses a self-signed certificate.
 * Warning: No error handling to keep the code short.
 */
class DummyClient : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    DummyClient(QTextStream& log)
        : _log(log),
          _sock(new QSslSocket(this)) {
        connect(_sock, SIGNAL(encrypted()), this, SLOT(onEncrypted()));
        connect(_sock, SIGNAL(sslErrors(QList<QSslError>)),
                this, SLOT(onSslErrors(QList<QSslError>)));
        connect(_sock, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)),
                this, SLOT(onErrors(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));

        // Trust store: which CAs or self-signed certs we are going to trust.
        //
        // We use setCaCertificates() instead than QSslSocket::addCaCertificates()
        // because we don't want to trust the ~200 default CAs.
        QList<QSslCertificate> trustedCas = QSslCertificate::fromPath("server-cert.pem");
        if (trustedCas.empty()) {
            qFatal("Error: no trusted Cas");
        }
        _sock->setCaCertificates(trustedCas);

        bool mutualAuth = false;
        if (mutualAuth) {
            // Our identity
            _sock->setPrivateKey("client-key.pem");
            _sock->setLocalCertificate("client-cert.pem");
        }

        _log << "Connecting" << endl;
        // Note: serverName must match the cert CN or alternative name.
        Qstring serverName = "myserver.example.org";
        _sock->connectToHostEncrypted(serverName, 995);
    }

signals:
    void done();

private slots:
    void onEncrypted() {
        _log << "onEncrypted" << endl;

        /* Everything is good. Start communicating. */

        emit done();
    }

    void onSslErrors(QList<QSslError> errors) {
        QSslError first = errors.takeFirst();
        _log << "onSslErrors: " << first.errorString() << endl;

        /* Something went wrong in the TLS handshake. Inform the user and quit! */

        emit done();
    }

    void onErrors(QAbstractSocket::SocketError) {
        _log << "onErrors: " << _sock->errorString() << endl;
        emit done();
    }

private:
    QTextStream& _log;
    QSslSocket* _sock;
};
```

Comment: finally a good example of how to do that properly without ignoring ssl errors. Thank you. But for some reason QWebsocketServer does not accept client's certificate, though it is added to store using `configuration.setCaCertificates(clientPemCertificate)`. Do you have any examples of that? Or any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtnetwork/qsslsocket.html

Look at the description of `QSslSocket::sslErrors`:

```
If you want to continue connecting despite the errors that have occurred,
you must call QSslSocket::ignoreSslErrors() from inside a slot connected 
to this signal.
```

**DISCLAIMER:** This is ***very*** ill-advised, as it leaves the server "wide open" to [man-in-the-middle attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)

Comment: DON'T FOLLOW THIS ANSWER (calling ignoreSslErrors). Its effect is that the client will not authenticate any more the server. Any kind of attacks are possible, including man-in-the-middle. See my answer instead.